# Why do i get a fatal error: 'include/hwComms/port.h: No such file or directory #include <include/hwComms/port.h>'?

Tags: c++, makefile, operating-system

The project I am working on is a step by step OS.

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.85.1 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Currently i am opening the folder "Create_Your_Own_OS"  and the objective is to compile "Lesson9" using the makefile.

The folder structure is as follows:

```
Create_Your_Own_OS
└───Lesson1
└───Lesson2
└───Lesson3
└───Lesson4
└───Lesson5
└───Lesson6
└───Lesson7
└───Lesson8
└───Lesson9
│   └───include
│       └───common
│       │          types.h
│       └───drivers
│       │          driver.h
│       │          keyboard.h
│       │          mouse.h
│       └───hwComms
│       │          interrupt.h
│       │          port.h
│    └───src
│       └───common
│       │          types.cpp
│       └───drivers
│       │          driver.cpp
│       │          keyboard.cpp
│       │          mouse.cpp
│       └───hwComms
│       │          interrupt.cpp
│       │          port.cpp
│  
└───linker.ld
└───makefile
```

The code of "Lesson9" is as follows:

port.h

```
#ifndef __MYOS__HWCOMMS__PORT_H
#define __MYOS__HWCOMMS__PORT_H

#include <common/types.h>

namespace myos
{
    namespace hwComms
    {

            class Port
            {
                protected:
                    Port(myos::common::uint16_t portnumber);
                    ~Port();
                    
                    myos::common::uint16_t portnumber;
            };

            class Port8bit: public Port
            {
                public:
                    Port8bit(myos::common::uint8_t portnumber);
                    ~Port8bit();
                    virtual void Write(myos::common::uint8_t portnumber);
                    virtual myos::common::uint8_t Read();

                protected:
                    static inline myos::common::uint8_t Read8(myos::common::uint16_t _port)
                    {
                        myos::common::uint8_t result;
                        __asm__ volatile("inb %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (_port));
                        return result;
                    }

                    static inline void Write8(myos::common::uint16_t _port, myos::common::uint8_t _data)
                    {
                        __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1" : : "a" (_data), "Nd" (_port));
                    }
            };

            class SlowPort8bit : public Port8bit
            {
                public:
                    SlowPort8bit(myos::common::uint8_t portnumber);
                    ~SlowPort8bit();

                    virtual void Write(myos::common::uint8_t portnumber);

                protected:
                    static inline void Write8Slow(myos::common::uint16_t _port, myos::common::uint8_t _data)
                    {
                        __asm__ volatile("outb %0, %1\njmp 1f\n1: jmp 1f\n1:" : : "a" (_data), "Nd" (_port));
                    }
            };    

            class Port16bit : public Port
            {
                public:
                    Port16bit(myos::common::uint16_t portnumber);
                    ~Port16bit();
                    virtual void Write(myos::common::uint16_t portnumber);
                    virtual myos::common::uint16_t Read();

                protected:
                    static inline myos::common::uint16_t Read16(myos::common::uint16_t _port)
                    {
                        myos::common::uint16_t result;
                        __asm__ volatile("inw %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (_port));
                        return result;
                    }

                    static inline void Write16(myos::common::uint16_t _port, myos::common::uint16_t _data)
                    {
                        __asm__ volatile("outw %0, %1" : : "a" (_data), "Nd" (_port));
                    }
            };

            class Port32bit : public Port
            {
                public:
                    Port32bit(myos::common::uint32_t portnumber);
                    ~Port32bit();
                    virtual void Write(myos::common::uint32_t portnumber);
                    virtual myos::common::uint32_t Read();
                
                protected:
                    static inline myos::common::uint32_t Read32(myos::common::uint16_t _port)
                    {
                        myos::common::uint32_t result;
                        __asm__ volatile("inl %1, %0" : "=a" (result) : "Nd" (_port));
                        return result;
                    }

                    static inline void Write32(myos::common::uint16_t _port, myos::common::uint32_t _data)
                    {
                        __asm__ volatile("outl %0, %1" : : "a"(_data), "Nd" (_port));
                    }
            };
    }
}

#endif
```

port.cpp

```
#include <include/hwComms/port.h>

using namespace myos::common;
using namespace myos::hwComms;


Port::Port(uint16_t portnumber)
{
    this->portnumber = portnumber;
}

Port::~Port()
{
}




Port8bit::Port8bit(uint8_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port8bit::~Port8bit()
{
}

void Port8bit::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    Write8(portnumber, data);
}

uint8_t Port8bit::Read()
{
    return Read8(portnumber);
}




SlowPort8bit::SlowPort8bit(uint8_t portnumber)
: Port8bit(portnumber)
{
}

SlowPort8bit::~SlowPort8bit()
{
}

void SlowPort8bit::Write(uint8_t data)
{
    Write8Slow(portnumber, data);
}




Port16bit::Port16bit(uint16_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port16bit::~Port16bit()
{
}

void Port16bit::Write(uint16_t data)
{
    Write16(portnumber, data);
}

uint16_t Port16bit::Read()
{
    return Read16(portnumber);
}




Port32bit::Port32bit(uint32_t portnumber)
: Port(portnumber)
{
}

Port32bit::~Port32bit()
{
}

void Port32bit::Write(uint32_t data)
{
    Write32(portnumber, data);
}

uint32_t Port32bit::Read()
{
    return Read32(portnumber);
}
```

Makefile

```
GPPARAMS = -m32 -Iinclude -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -Wno-write-strings
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = obj/loader.o \
obj/gdt.o \
obj/drivers/driver.o \
obj/hwComms/port.o \
obj/hwComms/interruptstubs.o \
obj/hwComms/interrupts.o \
obj/drivers/keyboard.o \
obj/drivers/mouse.o \
obj/kernel.o

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
mkdir -p $(@D)
gcc $(GPPARAMS) -o $@ -c $\<

obj/%.o: src/%.s
mkdir -p $(@D)
as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $\<

mykernel.bin: linkder.ld $(objects)
ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $\< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
sudo cp $\< /boot/mykernel.bin

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
mkdir iso
mkdir iso/boot
mkdir iso/boot/grub
cp $\< iso/boot/mykernel.bin
echo 'set timeout=0'                       \> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo 'set default=0'                      \>\> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo ''                                   \>\> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {'  \>\> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '  multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin'     \>\> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '  boot'                             \>\> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
echo '}'                                  \>\> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue --output=$@ iso
rm -rf iso
rm ../mykernel.iso
cp $@ ../

run: mykernel.iso
VBoxManage controlvm My_OS poweroff || true
sleep 3 && VBoxManage startvm My_OS

.PHONY: clean
clean:
rm -rf obj mykernel.bin mykernel.iso
```

To compile the "Lesson9" i go to the directory of "Lesson9" and execute "make" in the terminal. The output is this:

```
~/Desktop/OS_Development/OS_C/Build_Your_Own_OS/Lesson_9/myos$ make
mkdir -p obj/hwComms
gcc -m32 -Iinclude -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -Wno-write-strings -o obj/hwComms/port.o -c src/hwComms/port.cpp
src/hwComms/port.cpp:2:10: fatal error: include/hwComms/port.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <include/hwComms/port.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [makefile:18: obj/hwComms/port.o] Error 1
```

My attempts at solving the issue were the following:

1. Change <include/hwComms/port.h> to

   1. <myos/include/hwComms/port.h>
   2. "include/hwComms/port.h"
   3. "myos/include/hwComms/port.h"

Nothing of this attempts were successfull. I believe there might be an environment variable i need to set up.

Ideally i would like to set that variable in the makefile.

Comment: You have `gcc -m32 -Iinclude -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore -Wno-write-strings -o obj/hwComms/port.o -c src/hwComms/port.cpp` try `#include <hwComms/port.h>` the folder is relative to the folder you added as an include directory. In that case you added `include` as the include directory so it looked for `include/include/hwComms/port.h` with the current code.

Comment: That worked. A few more issues occurred with interruptstubs.s but i was able to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How do you find the file to be included? You **append** the path specified in `#include <...>` to the path specified in `-I`, and if the latter is relative, you append *that* to the current working directory of the compiler. If you have many `-I`, try each one in turn. If you have `#include "..."`, try the directory where the source file itself lives first, and then search those specified with `-I`.

Now let's apply this to your example.

You pass `-Iinclude` to `gcc`. Your source file lives in `src/hwComms`.

- Will `#include <include/hwComms/port.h>` work? No, because there is no `include/include/hwComms/port.h` anywhere.
- Will `#include <myos/include/hwComms/port.h>` work? No, because there is no `include/myos/include/hwComms/port.h` anywhere.
- Will `#include "include/hwComms/port.h"` work? No, because there is neither `src/hwComms/include/hwComms/port.h` nor
  `include/include/hwComms/port.h` anywhere.

My advice:

- Start with your preferred appearance of the include directives. For example, it makes no sense whatsoever to specify `#include <include/....>`, the directory name `include` conveys no information. Prefer either `#include <hwComms/port.h>` or `#include <myos/hwComms/port.h>`.
- Make sure you have all your header files (say, `hwComms/port.h` or `myos/hwComms/port.h`, depending on your chosen style) under the `include` subdirectory of the top level directory of your project (say `Lesson9`). So you would have e.g. `Lesson9/include/myos/hwComms/port.h`.
- Start `gcc` from the top level directory of your project (Lesson9).
- Pass `-Iinclude` to it.
- Alternatively, specify the *absolute* path (say `-I/home/yourname/Desktop/OS_Development/OS_C/Build_Your_Own_OS/Lesson_9/include`) and start `gcc` from whatever directory you want.
- You may also choose to place header files directly in the directory with the source files, or in one or more subdirectories thereof. In this case you may use `#include "foo.h"` and/or `#include "bar/baz.h"` and not worry about `-I` at all. This makes sense when the project is simple enough to have all the sources under the same directory.
- Finally, you might choose to use `#include "..."` style even for more complicated projects with many source and header directories. In this case, you will probably need directives that look something like `#include "../../foo/bar.h"`. In this case you again don't care about `-I`.